# Expectation for number of stops

Tags: expected-value, predictor, combinatorics

I was looking through old exam questions and stumbled upon a question in Henk Tijim's *Probability Exam Questions and Solutions* that rocked me, so I began to think of further questions. Here is the original question (and link to Henk's pdf; question 7e-30):

http://personal.vu.nl/h.c.tijms/ExamQuestionsUP.pdf

> An airport bus has 7 stops on its route. Assume that there are 25 distinct passengers on the bus and all passengers are equally likely to get off at any stop. Further, assume all passengers behave independently. The bus stops only if someone wants to get off. What is the probability that somebody gets off at each stop?

I began to wonder how to find the expectation of the number of stops. My thoughts, which I think are now wrong, were as follows:

> Have that each individual acts independently. There are a total of 25 people, each with 1/7 probability of getting off a stop. Since the bus stops ONLY if a person wants to get off, let's construct an indicator function as such
>   $$I_i= \begin{cases} 
>       1 & with\;prob\;p=\frac{1}{7} \\
>       0 & o.w \\
>    \end{cases}
> $$
>   for when the ith person wants to get off. Now, denote the following:
>   $$\textbf{X}:=number\;of\;stops\;the\;bus\;makes$$
>   It follows that
>   $$E[\textbf{X}]=E[\sum_{i=1}^{25} I_i]=\frac{25}{7}$$

What do people think? If I've gone wrong, please don't give me the answer. Give me a gentle push in the right direction as to how to think about this.

Comment: (1) Your formula does not answer the question, which asks for a *probability* and this expectation, since it exceeds $1$, obviously cannot be a probability.  (2) If the bus could hold more than $49$ people then your answer would exceed $7$, indicating the expected number of stops exceeds the actual number of stops available!

Comment: I'm answering an alternative question. Instead of looking for a probability, I am looking for expectation of number of stops. You are definitely right about my expectation being wrong. I just have no idea how to get in the right direction. Any suggestions?

Comment: Start by considering the chance that nobody chooses to get off at the first stop.  This approach will eventually require you to use the [Principle of Inclusion-Exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).